# 3.3 GN Distribute Points on faces- placeholder objects not visible

Tags: geometry-nodes

In this GN setup I am simply trying to show the 'placeholder instances' on my cube/plane before I add a Collection Instance on Points.  As you can see there are no visible 'placeholder instances' and when I add an instance nothing shows up (that I can see)
[image]

I think at one point I recreated the GN and it started working right but then I ended up here again.  Is there some basic thing I am missing or misunderstanding?  I have made sure that all objects have all transforms applied and origins at center of geometry. (Plane.001 is selected and ultimately I want to distribute Ferns and Rocks)

But here you can clearly see in a simple new project 'placeholder instances' and I am confident that when I add an instance object or collection, the objects will show up.  What might the problem be in the larger setup?
[image]

Comment: you can try to increase the density to e.g. 2000 - then you should see something. But since you didn't provide all necessary informations (like scale/size of your plane) we can just guess. so pls provide blend file. thx

Comment: Hello ! Your modifier is disabled. Click on the monitor icon to enable it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYvDw.png